# Is it possible to use use `parfor` for parallel computing in Matlab in these codes?

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, parfor

I am using `parfor` for parallel computing in Matlab. I am not familiar with this command. If that is possible, please look at my code below and tell me if I can write it with `parfor`.
These errors and warnings are appear in Matlab Editor:

- The parfor loop cannot be run due to the way variable `Dat` is used. (when I comment  line `Dat.normXpj = normXpj(pj,:);` This error is solved and other errors similar to the following error is appeared.
- The entire array or structure `Bound` is broadcast variable. This
  might result in unnecessary communication overhead.

  ```
  parfor pj = 1:size(normXpj,1)
  Dat.normXpj = normXpj(pj,:);

  if size(Dat.InitialGuess)==0
      X = (Bound(:,1)+(Bound(:,2)-Bound(:,1)).*rand(Nvar,1))';
  else
      X = Dat.InitialGuess;
  end

  [Xsqp, ~, FLAG,Options] = mopOPT(X,Dat);
  FEVALS = Options.funcCount;

  FES = FES+FEVALS;

  PSet(pj,:) = Xsqp;
  PFront(pj,:) = mop(Xsqp,Dat,0);
          if FLAG==-2
      disp('.......... Algo paso...');
  else
    F = PFront(pj,:);
    if Nobj==2
        plot(F(1,1),F(1,2),'*r'); grid on; hold on;
    elseif Nobj==3

     end
  end 
  end
  ```

Comment: hmm, No one helps? :(

Comment: Can you post the exact error message with `Dat` ?

Comment: this is what I got in Matlab Editor window when I mouse over `parfor`: The parfor loop cannot be run due to the way variable Dat is used @CrazyRat

Comment: OK. This is coherent with my answer.

Comment: so, really Noway? :((  @CrazyRat

Comment: As is, no way. Is it so hard to accept ? The content of the loop have to be modified, and I can't do it since I don't know what you want to do with your loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that it we can see that you're not using `Dat` in a way that is order-dependent, but the static analysis machinery of `parfor` cannot deduce that because of the way you're assigning into it. I think you can work around this by instead creating a whole new `Dat` for each iteration of the loop, like so:

```
Dat = struct('normXpj', rand(10,1), 'InitialGuess', 3);
normXpj = rand(10);
parfor idx = 1:10
    tmpDat = struct('normXpj', normXpj(:,idx), 'InitialGuess', Dat.InitialGuess);
    % use 'tmpDat'
    disp(tmpDat);
end
```

Comment: Why do you assume that `Dat` is a structure and not an object ? As you don't know what's inside `mopOPT(X,Dat)` or `mop(Xsqp,Dat,0)` for instance, it's hard to say that creating a new `Dat` at each iteration is the solution.

Comment: `Dat` is a structure. I tried to define a `tempDat` and stil I have broadcast variable error under each `Dat.blah` in the defined structure and other places in the loop i.e.,  `tempDat=struct('MatrixL',Dat.MatrixL,'Nk',Dat.Nk,'normXpj',Dat.normXpj) `mopOPT` and `mop` both contains a different function handle to be solved in `fmincon` @CrazyRat

Comment: By the way is there any chance to write this loop by `parfor` at least.`A1 = zeros(SG,Nvar);
for i = 1:SG
    A1(i,i)    =  1;
    A1(i,SG+i) = -1;
end` @CrazyRat

Comment: @Jamais avenir: Have you read [the documentation of parfor](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/introduction-to-parfor.html) ? It is clearly stated: "You cannot use a parfor-loop when an iteration in your loop depends on the results of other iterations".

Comment: That's right. I was thinking is there a way to modify this code for running with parfor. @CrazyRat

Comment: The OP's new question is still not order-dependent, and so it can run in `parfor`. You simply need to assign a whole row at a time into `A1`, like so: `A1 = zeros(SG,Nvar);
parfor i = 1:SG,
    row = zeros(1, Nvar);
    row([i, SG + i]) = [1, -1];
    A1(i, :) = row;
end`

Comment: Also note that the message about 'broadcast' variables is simply a warning indicating that you might be transferring more data than you realise - but you can proceed anyway.

Comment: Thats true, your code for my second question worked perfectly, But unfortunately, its run time is 1000 times more than normal `for`. But I the loop of my program is the one that I stated in the question which is still unsolved :( @Edric

Comment: It's no surprise it's much slower because it's not doing sufficient work to make `parfor` worthwhile - it's spending all the time shuffling the data back and forth. I'm confused as to what still doesn't work in your original question with the change to overwrite the whole value of `Dat`.

Comment: Hey @Edric You are write, with your solution the pafor is working despite those broadcast variables warnings. The time is significantly reduced from 60 sec to 40 sec :)))). Also,compare to normal `for` the results are almost similar with this `parfor` too. However, they are slightly deviated in order of `10^-4`. But in one case the difference is a lot (20). is it normal ? how can I reduce this difference?  @Edric

Comment: @edric Also, is there a way to open all cores before running the main code? I am using `delete (gcp); parpool('local',2)`, but if I run it on other computers I must change it to 4 maybe. Also, after opening cores I use `pause(5)` to make the system stabilized, does it really help to run the main code faster/?

Comment: Hm, numerical differences can occur because `parfor` workers run in single-computational-thread mode - but usually this results in only very small differences. Sounds like something else is going wrong.

Comment: To open a parallel pool of the "default" size - i.e. with the same number of workers as there are cores - just call `parpool('local')` (providing you haven't modified your `local` profile). I would remove the `pause`, I can't see any reason that would help.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no, unfortunately. At line:

```
Dat.normXpj = normXpj(pj,:);
```

you assign a value to `Dat.normXpj`, but you have to know that in a parfor loop there can be multiple iterations executing at the same time. So what value should be used for `Dat.normXpj` ? Matlab cannot decide, hence your error.

More generally, your code looks quite messy. I suppose you want to use `parfor` to increase execution speed. Probably a more efficient option would be to use the profiler (see [`profile`](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/profile.html)) to detect the bottlenecks in your code, and apply a correction if that's possible.

Best,

Comment: `Dat.normXpj` is a 3*55 Matrix which is remained constant during the program. This look is run for 55 times and an optimization problem with `fmincon` is run there. So thats the most time consuming part of the whole code. @crazy-rat

Comment: Well, if `Dat.normXpj` is constant, why do you redefine it at every iteration in your loop ? Please provide some coherent information.

Comment: It was a mistake. It changes every iteration, only the size of of loop size(normXpj,1) is kept constant. @CrazyRat

Comment: :((( bad times, Thanks for your help anyway @crazyrat

Comment: Edric answer is working, Thanks for your help as well. @CrazyRat